# Mongodb 3.2. C# getUsers()

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm a beginner with mongodb. I want to findout in my Software, which user are exist on the database. I have found the command

```
IMongoDatabase.getUsers()
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getUsers/

But i can't find, how it works in c# for the mongo db 3.2. I tried

```
IMongoDatabase.RunCommand()
```

but this want a BsonDocumentCommand. I dont't know, how i convert the command getUsers() in a BsonDocumentCommand.

We have upgraded the Software to Mongo Version 3.2. And we use the c#-driver 
2.3.0 (beta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mongo shell, you can type the name of a function without the parenthesis () and see the definition for it.
Example:

```
> db.getUsers
```

Will return

```
function (args) {
        var cmdObj = {
            usersInfo: 1 //this is the important bit
        };
        Object.extend(cmdObj, args);
        var res = this.runCommand(cmdObj);
        //etc....
```

So, in our case, you'll need to run the `usersInfo` cmd.

Something like

```
client.GetDatabase("dbNameGoesHere").RunCommand<BsonDocument>("{usersInfo: 1}");
```

Comment: Where can we get the command names like {usersInfo: 1}. I want to get the Database stats and collectionNames. Can you help me with db.stats and db.getCollectionNames commnads

Comment: Ask a separate question on stackoverflow.com